# Is it possible to force charges into one plate of a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, charge, physics, electron

As we know, a capacitor stores *energy*, but the net amount of *charge* in it doesn't change. If an electron enters one plate, another leaves the other plate. If the other plate is floating, the entering electron *shall not pass* or is soon thrown out the front door.

That is, in regular usage. But with special equipment (whether real or theoretical), is it possible to force more electrons into one plate while the other one is floating? Or into any chunk of conductive material, I suppose, since the other plate doesn't actually play a role here. And would the result be any kind of stable?

Edit: as the comments show the answer is "yeah obviously", so let's focus on whether it can be done with as few moving parts as possible and whether the charge stored as such can be employed for any useful work. Like, if you tried to power a circuit from a capacitor that had a surplus of electrons, I assume that "pressure" would want to spread out over the wires. Would that be an electric current? Would transistors still work in the presence of too many electrons?

Comment: Sure. Notice it's equivalent to charging the capacitor normally (+ one plate and - the other), plus charging up the whole thing with static electricity (+ both plates)

Comment: Eh yeah, don't know why I didn't think of that. So the real question is how to generate that static electricity, but there are probably many ways to do that.

Comment: Van de Graaff generator probably. As far as I know, it's hard to do with electric circuits.

Comment: You could charge a capacitor as you do normally, then disconnect it and disassemble it. Voila, two statically charged plates! I presume that if you then connect either of them to another blob of conductive stuff, those charges equalize and the blob is also charged.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom You've just invented the [Electrophorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophorus), or at least something like it, well done. Note that dismantling the capacitor requires you to do work pulling apart the attracting plates, which is what powers the generator part of it.

Comment: indeed, or you could use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimshurst_machine or a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_water_dropper etc. Static electricity has been studied although we found that the non-static sort is way more useful. Maybe you will have fun doing some of these experiments.

Comment: @user253751, It's hard to measure the minuscule static charge that could be produced by a low-voltage electronic circuit, but how about a [_Cockcroft-Walton generator_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator)? Would you call that an "electronic circuit?"

Comment: ROFL **useful work** .  You assume much from a capacitor.  No matter what you do **real or theoretical**, no work will be done by a capacitor.

Comment: Hmm. Something missed in all this: [method of images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges). May as well add it to the heap.